# Highlighting a cell from a dynamic php table using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

When I test the code it works fine if it is running using a static table. But when I run it on my page that is generating a dynamic table nothing happens.

JavaScript code

```
    <script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#Weekly td').each(function() {
if ($(this).text() == 'Yes') {
    $(this).closest('td').css('background-color', 'yellow');
}
});
</script>
```

php code

```
if ($WeeklyResult->num_rows > 0){
   echo "<Table id=Weekly>";
   $headerRow = TRUE;
   while ($row = $WeeklyResult->fetch_assoc()){
       if($headerRow){
           $headerRow = FALSE;
           echo "<tr>";
           foreach (array_keys($row) as $header){
               echo"<th>$header</th>";

           }
           echo "</tr>";
       }
       echo "<tr>";
       foreach ($row as $value){
           echo "<td>$value</td>";

       }
       echo "</tr>";
   }
   echo "</table>";

}
```

Comment: In dynamic generation where have you add id **Weekly**. I think it should be assigned to some row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(document).ready will help You. Just try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Weekly td').each(function() {
            if ($(this).text() == 'Yes') {
                $(this).closest('td').css('background-color', 'yellow');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The table must exist before you perform any actions on it. Be sure the js is fired after the PHP has been interpreted and the page has been rendered.

Comment: so if I put exit () at the end of the PHP then run the JS it should work? edit: just tried that no dice....is there a way to hold off the JS from running?

Comment: Exiting the PHP process will only terminate the request and send the response. What you'd want to do is use a callback that fires when the document is ready.

Answer (score 0):

You can changing the jQuery code like this:

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
    $('#Weekly td').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == 'Yes') {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This way the code is ran when the document is ready and the DOM has been fully built.